# Get exceptions from Databricks Notebook in Azure Datafactory pipeline

Tags: python, azure, exception, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I've added a Databricks Notebook to a Datafactory pipeline. If the Python script inside the notebook throws an exception, this exception will not be mentioned by the pipeline. I know there is a runPageUrl where I can see the results. But I want the pipeline to know if an error occurred in the Python script. Is there a way to pass exception information to the pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. I just had to add assertion to the exceptions. Next step is to find out how to get the error message in the outcome of the activity in the pipeline...

Comment: I am also looking for same, Can you please elaborate?? with example would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ravibhat What I do is the following:`try:... except: assert False, logMessage`. The assert will let the activity in the pipeline know it failed. Logging I do now in Application Insights https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Python.

Comment: That's not solve the issue because you get same result raising an exception.